# Creating a Person model from forms.py data

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to figure out how to create Person model from the data I get from a small application I created called "survey". The survey application uses a SessionWizardView which splits a survey over multiple pages.

I keep getting this error

> File
>   "/Users/brendan/Dropbox/workspace/bias_experiment/src/survey/models.py",
>   line 38, in Person
>       email = forms.SurveyFormA.sender(max_length=200) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SurveyFormA' localhost:src brendan$

**models.py**

```
from django import forms 
from django.db import models
from survey.forms import SurveyFormA, SurveyFormB


class Person(models.Model):
    email = forms.SurveyFormA.sender(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

**forms.py**

This is an example of some of the questions I have in my forms.py

```
class SurveyFormA(forms.Form):
    sender = forms.EmailField(label='What is your email address?', required = False)               
    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years = range(1995, 1900, -1)), label='What is your Date of Birth?', required = False)

    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'FM'

    SEX = (
        ("", "----------"), 
        (MALE, "Male"),
        (FEMALE, "Female"),
           )   
    sex = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=SEX, initial= "", label='What sex are you?', required = False)

class SurveyFormB(forms.Form):
    ....
    more questions here
    ....
```

I am using Python 2.7.3 and Django 1.6.2 (I will try to update soon)

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Form fields and Model fields are not the same - you can't use a Form field in a Model. Seems you need to read the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models) a bit more.

Comment: Hi Ben, The only reason I used forms.py and form clases it because I thought I was meant to "The first step in creating a form wizard is to create the Form classes. These should be standard django.forms.Form classes, covered in the forms documentation. These classes can live anywhere in your codebase, but convention is to put them in a file called forms.py in your application." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#defining-form-classes Or maybe Im missing something?

Comment: Yup, that's correct for making a form wizard. But that has nothing to do with models. If you then want to use the data from the form to save a model instance, you'd need to either use a ModelForm or save it manually. But either way, your model needs to be defined properly with django.db.models.EmailField etc instead of django.forms.EmailField. Form fields know how to render as HTML forms, Model fields know how to save and retrieve data from a database.

Comment: @Ben I eventually followed your instruction and used a ModelForm. If you write your comment up as an answer I would be happy to accept

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
email = forms.SurveyFormA.sender(max_length=200)
```

forms represents the Django module.  Try this instead:

```
email = SurveyFormA.sender(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Tried your solution but it gives me an error `AttributeError: type object 'SurveyFormA' has no attribute 'sender'`

Comment: 'sender' is a class variable, but you're trying to call it like a function.  I'm not sure what your intention is without seeing the rest of the code, but you need to go one way or the other.

Comment: That makes sense. I added some more code to try describe better what I'm trying to achieve. The class variable `email` in my forms.py holds the value of the users email address, I want to get that into my models.py Person model so I can store it in my MySQL database. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Sorry, at home now and I'm taking a closer look at your code, and I think Ben is right - you need to take another look at Django's docs.  Specifically, how to define your model subclasses.  Good luck!